# Run Time Type Identification in Java

Tags: java

Consider a super class reference variable is holding the reference of a sub class object and that particular sub class overrides one of its super class method. Now , if we invoke the overridden method , the sub class implementation will be called. In Java does this involve RTTI ..?

```
class A { void Show(){ System.out.println("This is A"); } }

class B extends A{
    void show(){
        System.out.println("This is B");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does involve runtime type identification.  The Java VM looks up the appropriate method to call based on the object's type.

However, when most people refer to "run-time type information", they're talking about C++.

If you're asking whether the Java VM uses C++ RTTI, the answer is no.

Comment: Thank you. So the RTTI implementation in Java is different from C++ , right..?

Comment: I think "late binding" or "dynamic binding" is the java term.

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not. RTTI (run-time type information) is a C++ term that refers to retaining type information at run time, and is therefore more related to reflection in Java. What you are asking about is just the usual dynamic dispatch of object-oriented languages. Dynamic dispatch (determining where to *dispatch* a method invocation based on run-time types, that is, *dynamic* information) is an integral concept to object-oriented programming, whereas reflection is not really necessary for a language to be object-oriented.

Answer (score 3):

What your example illustrates is simple polymorphic or dynamic dispatching of method calls.  In C++ terminology, you'd need to declare the method as "virtual" for this to happen, so it is called virtual method call / dispatching.  In Java, no special syntax is required, and it potentially happens for any instance method call.

Whether this amounts to "RTTI" is a moot point.  (For a start, it depends on what you mean by the term!)  Certainly, some information is needed to allow dispatching to take place, but (in theory) that need not be sufficient to allow runtime identification of types.  In the Java case, the details of what that information is, and how it is represented are JVM specific.

There are some further salient points:

- The bytecodes emitted by the Java bytecode compiler have three distinct bytecodes for calling an instance method.  The "invokeinterface" and "invokevirtual" bytecodes are used when virtual method dispatching may be required, and the "invokespecial" bytecode is used when it is not.
- The JIT compiler further optimizes the native code to avoid doing virtual method dispatching in cases where it is not necessary.
- Even when the compilers manage to do away with the overheads of virtual method dispatching, each object needs some way of identifying its actual class (type) at runtime in order to support the `instanceof` operator, up-casting, the `Object.getClass()` method and various things that depend on them.  So from that perspective, some kind of RTTI is always present.

Comment: does the Compiler level implementation of  dynamic method dispatching involve  virutal table look up..?

Answer (score 1):

It is called a "virtual lookup" I believe and yes it has a runtime impact if that what you mean by RTTI.

Answer (score 1):

For a Java method call on a *class* (not an *interface*) the JVM doesn't need to worry about what specific class it is.  All of the `show` methods in classes derived from A are in element 26 (to pick a number) of the specific class's method table.  So the JVM only needs to fetch the class pointer from the object header, index into the method table to the 26th entry (which is a runtime constant) and invoke that method.

Interfaces are more complicated and something closer to a hashtable lookup must be used to find the method.